SQL IIF result is based on data type?
following statement gives Conversion failed error.
SELECT IIF(500<1000, 'YES', 0);

does its result based on data type?
i need following statment should work.
SELECT IIF(500<1000, 'YES', 0);

as i need this for create statement like
declare @Old MONEY = 0,@New MONEY
select CONCAT('Current value changed from ''' , IIF(@Old = 0,'None', @Old) , ''' to ''' , IIF(@New = 0,'None', @New) , ''', ')


Which dbms are you using? IIF is a non-standard function.

If you have several rows in your result, some with 'YES' as value in that one column, some with 0: what should be the datatype of that column?

I assume you are using SQL Server's IIF() function.  This function behaves similarly to a CASE expression.  In a CASE expression, all branches (possible outputs) must have the same type.  This means that, in your code:
SELECT IIF(500 < 1000, 'YES', 0);

The if and else values should either both be strings or integers.  It makes no sense to speak of the string literal 'YES' as being an integer, so the following is probably what you need:
SELECT IIF(500 < 1000, 'YES', '0');

Here, we have made the zero into a string literal.  The above version should run without any conversion error.

Although the @tim-biegeleisen answer is totally correct you can do this as well.
select CONCAT('Current value changed from ''' , IIF(@Old = 0,'None', CAST(@Old as VARCHAR(20))) , ''' to ''' , IIF(@New = 0,'None', CAST(@New as VARCHAR(20))) , ''', ')

So basically we can use CAST to convert numbers to strings.
